# Drools not working correctly with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, drools

I want to use Drools with Spring Boot for Bean Validation but I have narrowed the problem down to this few lines of code:

The Main-Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        check();
    }

    public static void check() {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
        //go
        Patient patient = new Patient("Hans", "Mueller");
        kSession.insert(patient);
        kSession.fireAllRules();
    }
}
```

`Patient` is an Entity with just an id, firstname and lastname with getter and setter.

The kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

and two rules

```
package com.sample

import com.sample.Patient;

rule "Test"
    when
        eval(1 == 1)
    then
        System.out.println("This rule is always fired");
end

rule "Patient"
    when
        exists Patient()
    then
        System.out.println("Patient found");
end
```

When **not** calling `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)` (like above) everything works fine:

```
15:50:12.730 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl - Starting Engine in PHREAK mode
15:50:12.820 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was INACTIVE is nw FIRING_ALL_RULES
15:50:12.821 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - Fire Loop
This rule is always fired
15:50:12.827 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - Fire Loop
Patient found
15:50:12.827 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - Fire Loop
15:50:12.827 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was FIRING_ALL_RULES is nw HALTING
15:50:12.827 [main] DEBUG org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda - State was HALTING is nw INACTIVE
```

However, when I add `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)` to the main, only one rule is fired:

```
This rule is always fired
```

Not even the logging of `org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda` is visible anymore.

I have no idea whats going wrong? I expect the same output in both situations. Is SpringBoot doing something in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everybody that has the same problem and reads my question:

I haven't solved it directly but the problem has something to do with netbeans. Everything works fine when starting the application via command line. So this is the way to go.

Comment: I am debugging apps of drools + spring boot using eclipse. And has the problem of drool not firing until l see this post. Then I run the apps directly in Cli, and see that drools start firing

Answer (score 3):

I know the question already has its accepted answer, but I feel it would be nice to state here that after **removing** the `spring-boot-devtools` (Maven dependency, in my case), the bug is gone.

Reference: ["No rules are fired in helloworld using Spring rest controller!" on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/N_sqhpkhAdM).

Comment: I could have given you +100 if that would be possible, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Aman I'm glad that my answer helped :) Maven and it's crazy dependency issues..

Answer (score 0):

I added below lines in `kmodule.xml`. It worked in Eclipse too.

```
<kbase name="rules" packages="rules" e**ventProcessingMode="cloud" equalsBehavior="equality" declarativeAgenda="enabled"** >
    <ksession name="rulesSession"/>
</kbase>
```